# appending to a association_proxy does not emit an event:

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following ORM class:

```python
class Video(Base):
    ...
    public_tag_entries = relationship("VideoTagEntry")
    tags = association_proxy("public_tag_entries", "value")
```

Furthermore i have associated an event on append :

```python
def video_tag_added(target, value, initiator):
    print "tag added"

event.listen(Video.public_tag_entries, 'append', video_tag_added)
```

when I append to the public_tag_entries, the event is emitted

```python
video.public_tag_entries.append(VideoTagEntry(value = "foo"))
```

However when i add using:

```python
video.tags.append("foo")
```

the event is not emitted.

I tried to register an event on the video.tags association proxy, but that seems not to work.

Question: is this expected and correct behavior, or is this a bug? And is there a work around, or am i simply doing something wrong.

I would expect the association proxy to trigger orm events to the underlying attribute.

Thanks,
Jacco

Answer (score 1):

can't reproduce (using 0.7.9):

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import event


Base = declarative_base()

class VideoTagEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'vte'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    video_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('video.id'))
    value = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class Video(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'video'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    public_tag_entries = relationship("VideoTagEntry")
    tags = association_proxy("public_tag_entries", "value")

canary = []
def video_tag_added(target, value, initiator):
    print "tag added"
    canary.append(value)

event.listen(Video.public_tag_entries, 'append', video_tag_added)

video = Video()

video.public_tag_entries.append(VideoTagEntry(value="foo"))

video.tags.append("foo")

assert len(canary) == 2
```

output:

```
tag added
tag added
```

So you need to alter this test case to look more like your code to see what the difference is.